A problem about polynomial approximation under $L^p$ norm.
The following is a problem from Foundations of Modern Analysis by Avner Friedman:

4.3.7 Let $n$ be a positive integer, $1 \le p < \infty$, and let $f(x)$ be a continuous function on $0 \le x \le 1$. Then there exists a unique polynomial $Q_n$ of degree $n$ such that for any other polynomial $P_n$ of degree $n$
$$\int_0^1 |f(x) - P_n(x)|^p dx > \int_0^1 |f(x) - Q_n(x)|^p dx.$$

I can see how I might prove this if instead of polynomials of degree $n$ we consider polynomials of degree $\le n$. Such polynomials form a finite-dimensional subspace $\cal P_n$ of $(C[a,b], \lVert \phantom x \rVert_p)$, and the norm is strictly convex, so by the results of an earlier problem there is a unique polynomial $Q \in \cal P_n$ such that
$$\inf_{P \in \cal P_n} \lVert f - P \rVert_p = \lVert f - Q \rVert_p.$$
I would expect the solution to be along these lines since this section of the book is about finite-dimensional normed linear spaces, but I don't quite see how to extend it to the case where the polynomials must have exactly degree $n$, since the set of such polynomials is not a linear subspace. I thought for a moment that perhaps I could show that the polynomial $Q$ of the above argument is guaranteed to be of maximal degree, i.e. $n$, but that cannot be the case since $f$ could be a polynomial of lower degree.
Can my approach be salvaged, or do I need to come up with something completely different?

Does he say the coefficient of $x^n$ can’t be zero?

@Aruralreader He does not say so explicitly, but every definition I have encountered of polynomial of degree $n$ says that $n$ is the degree of the highest term with nonzero coefficient.

But sure, I have also had the thought that maybe it is an error in the problem. On the other hand, the claim (as written) seems like it could be true.

One has to use not only compactness but also the fact that proper unit ball is strictly convex.

Wait a minute. The problem statement must be wrong. The function $f(x) = 0$ doe not have a best approximation by degree 1 polynomials for example.

I realized that the problem statement must be wrong. Consider for example $f(x) = 0$ and $n=1$. Then $f$ can be approximated arbitrarily well by degree 1 polynomials $P(x) = ax + b$, $a \ne 0$, but no such polynomial makes $\lVert f - P \rVert_p$ vanish.
I will therefore assume that the problem is meant to say degree $\le n$, in which case my original strategy should work.
